# Registration module, Rules, how to add the node-title of the registrated entity to notification mail

Tags: 7, rules, users

I have a registration form built with [registration module](http://drupal.org/project/registration) to enable users to reserve tickets for events. Now i want to send notification mails to the site administrators to inform them about new registrations. The mails are sent via Rules "After saving a new registration" and i have all fields included except the node-title... the only "hints" of this field are the tokens [registration:registration-id] and [registration:url]. Can i transform these to human-readable items somehow? Is there a way to connect the registration-form to the specific node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to add another action before the mail-action: "Fetch entity by id". Set the type to "Node" and the data selector to "registration:entity-id". After this all the node-specific fields were available for the mail-action.